# Access individual elements of an array of several arrays, Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I am using a function that returns array of several arrays let say A. I don't know how to access each individual element. Thus, I am thinking to rearrange A to a matrix of two arrays so I could access them. The other option is to rearrange A (can be of order 10**6) to a big sparse matrix, the problem here is again I don't know how to achieve this. I need to point out I want to avoid **Forloop**. I know the total length of `A` (here is 7) but don't know the length of each individual array. Here is an example of `A`

```
A = array([[array([0, 1, 4])],
            [array([0, 1, 2, 5])],
            [array([1, 2, 3, 6])],
            [array([2, 3, 7])],
            [array([0, 4, 5, 8])],
            [array([1, 4, 5, 6, 9])],
            [array([ 2,  5,  6,  7, 10])]])
```

and here is the index I am trying to change it to

```
B = (array([0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6]),
array([0,1,4,0,1,2,5,1,2,3,6,2,3,7,0,4,5,8,1,4,5,6,9,2,5,6,7, 10]))
```

If this is impossible to do. Can you help me see if I can access each individual element, for example is there a way I could do the following

```
A[4][2] = 5
```

or

```
 A[2][3] = 6
```

thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array **A** is an *array containing lists of arrays*. You can just flatten your array to get an *array of arrays*.

```
A_flat = A.flatten()
```

Now you can access each individual array like this:

```
>> A_flat[4][2]
5

>> A_flat[2][3]
6
```

Comment: are you sure about that? what is the *shape* of the flattened array?

Comment: The shape is (7,). So it is not a real matrix. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Is it possible to imbed A_flat to a `sparse matrix` of 7 by 7?